# Filtering ManyToMany in Django-Admin/Django-Form by related field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin, django-filter

I want to filter my ManyToMany by related fields in the Django-Admin (create/edit object). For example i have 3 Models:

Model 1 - Boardgame: Name (CharField), Genre (ForeignKey)
Model 2 - Location: Name (CharField), Boardgame (ManyToMany)
Model 3 - Genre: Name (CharField)

Now in the django-admin when i edit a location i can add and remove boardgames via horizontal-filter. Now i want an extra select Field where i can define a genre, so the manyToMany choices change based on what i select on the genre-select.

But i can't find an option to

1. Include the genre-select
2. To filter by the genre-select

Anyone here having an idea, how to solve this?

What i tried so far:

1. Tried the django_advanced_filter because google lead me to it -> It is just for filtering in the "overview"-tab
2. Tried to find a function that can do this natively in the admin -> Didn't find anything
3. Had the idea to accomplish this via a modelsForm but wasn't able to find a possibility to add there a filter tab.
4. Read something about django_filters, that maybe an option, but didnt find a possibility to integrate it in the forms.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a look at the [django-formset](https://github.com/jrief/django-formset) package?

From reading your question, this example https://django-formset.fly.dev/dual-selector/#filtering-select-options shows what you're probably looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that sounds like the thing I needed. We just need something that is working with django3.2 or need to upgrade to django4 to use this. If anyone else has an idea for django3.2 i would be happy to hear about it.